# ¿Como creo un factor a partir de variable dummy?

Tags: r

Tengo unos datos en un data.frame como los siguientes:

```
|Pregunta1Muy de acuerdo |Pregunta1De acuerdo |Pregunta1En desacuerdo |Pregunta1Muy en desacuerdo |
|:-----------------------|:-------------------|:----------------------|:--------------------------|
|Muy de acuerdo          |NA                  |NA                     |NA                         |
|NA                      |NA                  |En desacuerdo          |NA                         |
|NA                      |NA                  |En desacuerdo          |NA                         |
|NA                      |NA                  |En desacuerdo          |NA                         |
|Muy de acuerdo          |NA                  |NA                     |NA                         |
|Muy de acuerdo          |NA                  |NA                     |NA                         |
|NA                      |NA                  |En desacuerdo          |NA                         |
|NA                      |NA                  |En desacuerdo          |NA                         |
|NA                      |De acuerdo          |NA                     |NA                         |
|Muy de acuerdo          |NA                  |NA                     |NA                         |
```

Que se pueden reproducir usando:

```
df_dummy <- structure(list(`Pregunta1Muy de acuerdo` = c("Muy de acuerdo",NA, NA, NA, "Muy de acuerdo", "Muy de acuerdo", NA, NA, NA, "Muy de acuerdo"), 
               `Pregunta1De acuerdo` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "De acuerdo", NA), 
               `Pregunta1En desacuerdo` = c(NA, "En desacuerdo", "En desacuerdo", "En desacuerdo", NA, NA, "En desacuerdo", "En desacuerdo", NA, NA), 
               `Pregunta1Muy en desacuerdo` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Claramente corresponden a una variable factor que en el proceso de carga de datos fue separada en sus categorías. Para cada fila solo una de columnas tiene un valor diferente a `NA`.

Lo que quiero es crear un único factor a partir de esas variables, es decir, una variable que se llame `Pregunta1` y tenga los niveles `Muy de acuerdo`, `De acuerdo`, `En desacuerdo` y `Muy en desacuerdo`. La idea es que elimine los `NA` y deje solamente el valor válido. Qedaría algo así:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
Pregunta1     
<chr>         
1 Muy de acuerdo
2 En desacuerdo 
3 En desacuerdo 
4 En desacuerdo 
5 Muy de acuerdo
6 Muy de acuerdo
7 En desacuerdo 
8 En desacuerdo 
9 De acuerdo    
10 Muy de acuerdo
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Se puede usar la función `coalesce()`, de `dplyr`. Esa función toma dos o más variables y para cada fila reemplaza los `NA` con el primer valor válido (no `NA`) que encuentra en esa misma fila.

De manera simple se podría usar:

```
library(tidyverse)
coalesce(df_dummy$`Pregunta1Muy de acuerdo`, 
  df_dummy$`Pregunta1De acuerdo`, 
  df_dummy$`Pregunta1En desacuerdo`, 
  df_dummy$`Pregunta1Muy en desacuerdo`)
```

Que regresa un vector con las características indicadas.

Sin embargo es un poco trabajoso escribir todos los nombres de variables. Si las únicas variables que hay en un data frame son las que tienen el problema (como es el caso de la pregunta) se puede aplicar la función `reduce()` de la librería `purrr` para aplicar `coalesce()` a todas las columnas.

```
df_dummy %>% reduce(coalesce)
```

Y ya no hay que escribir los nombres.

Si hay muchas variables que comparten el mismo problema y tienen los mismos niveles de factor y la misma convención de nombres se podría separar esas variables usando `split` y después aplicarle la reducción a cada parte. Puede sonar raro, pero es muy común en base de datos que provienen de encuestas.

Creo unos datos simples que tendrían ese problema:

```
df_muchos_dummies <- cbind(df_dummy, df_dummy %>% rename_all(~str_replace(., "1", "2")))
```

Aquí están `Pregunta1` y `Pregunta2`, solo que repartidas en muchas columnas. Como los nombres tienen un patrón regular puedo usar una `str_remove` para eliminar el "subnombre" y quedarme solamente con el nombre de la pregunta. Así defino unos "grupos" y `split.default()` arma lista con todas las variables que tienen el mismo nombre.

Sobre esa lista es usamos `map_df` para aplicar a cada elemento (un data.frame que reune a las variables con el mismo nombre) el `reduce(coalesce)` y obtener el resultado final como un data.frame.

```
df_muchos_dummies %>% 
  #mutate_all(as.character) %>%  #coalesce fallaría con factores
  split.default(str_remove(names(.), 
                           #subnombres separados por | (ó lógico en expresiones regulares)
                           "Muy de acuerdo|De acuerdo|En desacuerdo|Muy en desacuerdo")) %>% 
  map_df(reduce, coalesce)
```

Para cada caso particular habría que modificar los "subnombres", pero la lógica es bastante flexible.

¿Qué tal si en lugar de tener los valores de la categoría en cada columna tengo 0 y 1?

Se podría usar `imap` para reemplazar el `1` por el nombre de la columna y el `0` por `NA`

Creo unos datos de ejemplo:

```
df_dummy %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(!is.na(.), 1, 0)) -> df_dummy_01

imap_dfc(df_dummy_01, ~ifelse(.x == 0, NA, .y))
```