# Problemas con limpieza de bases de datos en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo problemas con esta base de datos en R, se supone que son datos relacionadas con videojuegos pero necesito cambiar todas estas filas, lo que debo hacer extraer de cada columna los años y agregarlos como una nueva columna, luego de alguna manera juntar todas las columnas en una y sustituir sus valores en los que tenían el año por el tipo de videojuego que es para después nombrar esa columna como `Genre`. Cabe mencionar que los `NA` son de tipo texto y no `NA` convencionales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una solución usando `tidyverse`. La función clave es `coalesce()`, que para varios vectores regresa regresa el primer valor no `NA`. En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424775/como-creo-un-factor-a-partir-de-variable-dummy) hay más detalles de como usarla para hacer esto mismo. Como esa primera pregunta es duplicada paso a la segunda, que creo que no tiene respuesta aún en este sitio.

Tu segunda pregunta involucra reemplazar a los valores no `NA` de tus columnas por el título de las columnas. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta usa `across()` y `cur_column()`.

Van unos datos simulados:

```
structure(list(action = c(2008, NA, NA, NA), adventure = c(NA, 
NA, 1996, NA), fighting = c(NA, 2006, NA, NA), misc = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Que se ven así y se llaman `juegos`

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  action adventure fighting  misc
   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1   2008        NA       NA    NA
2     NA        NA     2006    NA
3     NA      1996       NA    NA
4     NA        NA       NA  2020

juegos %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),                 #Acá se podrían seleccionar solo algunas columnas
                         ~ifelse(!is.na(.x),  #Si no es NA
                                 cur_column(),#Le asigno el nombre de la columna
                                 .x))) %>%    #Si no la dejo como está
             reduce(coalesce) -> genre        #junto las columnas conservando solo el primer valor no NA
```

La función `across()` es relativamente nueva y sirve para aplicar una función a un conjunto de columnas. En este caso es a todas con `everything()`, pero podría ser solo una o una rango de definido con `:`. Es función tiene una función ayudante que se llama `cur_column()` que regresa el nombre de la columna sobre la que está operando. Entonces dentro del `across` uso un `ifelse()` para que, cuando no es `NA` el valor de la columna lo reemplace por el nombre y cuando es `NA` lo deje como está. Luego aplico el mismo esquema de `reduce(coalesce)` para reducirlo a una sola columna en la que quedan los valores no `NA`.

Es un poco complicado, pero funciona.